# TeeChart MonoDroid version

Tags: xamarin.android, teechart

I've just started to evaluate TeeChart MonoDroid version and have some minor issues from the following code:

```
TChart _Chart = new TChart(context);
Bar _Bar1 = new Bar(_Chart.Chart);
Bar _Bar2 = new Bar(_Chart.Chart);

_Chart.Axes.Left.Increment = 25;
_Chart.Axes.Left.SetMinMax(0, 100);
_Chart.Axes.Left.Labels.Style = AxisLabelStyle.Mark;
_Chart.Axes.Visible = false;
_Chart.Walls.Left.Visible = false;
_Chart.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;
_Chart.Panel.Transparent = true;
_Chart.Walls.Back.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
_Chart.Walls.Back.Width = 200;
_Chart.Walls.Back.Transparency = 90;
_Chart.Walls.Back.Gradient.Visible = false;
_Chart.Walls.Bottom.Size = 10;
_Chart.Walls.Bottom.Width = 200;
_Chart.Legend.Visible = false;
_Chart.Header.Visible = false;
_Chart.Aspect.View3D = true;
_Chart.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);

_Bar1.Add(50, "50%");
_Bar1.Depth = 10;
_Bar1.Pen.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
_Bar1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
_Bar1.MarksOnBar = true;
_Bar1.MultiBar = MultiBars.Stacked;
_Bar1.Marks.Style = MarksStyles.Label;
_Bar1.Marks.Transparent = true;
_Bar1.Marks.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
_Bar1.Marks.Font.Size = 18;
_Bar1.Marks.Font.Bold = true;
_Bar1.CustomBarWidth = 75;
_Bar1.MarksLocation = MarksLocation.Center;

_Chart.Series.Add(_Bar1);

_Bar2.Add(50, "50%");
_Bar2.Depth = 10;
_Bar2.Pen.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
_Bar2.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
_Bar2.MarksOnBar = true;
_Bar2.MultiBar = MultiBars.Stacked;
_Bar2.Marks.Style = MarksStyles.Label;
_Bar2.Marks.Transparent = true;
_Bar2.Marks.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
_Bar2.Marks.Font.Size = 18;
_Bar2.Marks.Font.Bold = true;
_Bar2.CustomBarWidth = 75;
_Bar2.MarksLocation = MarksLocation.Center;

_Chart.Series.Add(_Bar2);

AbsoluteLayout absl = new AbsoluteLayout(this);

absl.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);

absl.AddView(_Chart, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(400, 1200, 0, 0));
```

This produces a stacked single bar, 50% split between red and black.  My issues are as follows:

1) No matter what I try, I can't get the View to be transparent - I'd like any underlying View to show through the Chart.

2) I can't seem to make the bottom "wall" any deeper - I'd like it to be as deep as the bar depth.

I am also experiencing a "flashing" issue when I attempt to update the chart using the following code:

```
_Chart.Series[0].Clear();
_Chart.Series[1].Clear();

_Bar1.Add(HistoryRed, String.Format("{0:0,0.00}%", HistoryRed));
_Bar1.Depth = 10;
_Bar1.Pen.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
_Bar1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
_Bar1.MarksOnBar = true;
_Bar1.MultiBar = MultiBars.Stacked;
_Bar1.Marks.Style = MarksStyles.Label;
_Bar1.Marks.Transparent = true;
_Bar1.Marks.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
_Bar1.Marks.Font.Size = 18;
_Bar1.Marks.Font.Bold = true;
_Bar1.CustomBarWidth = 75;
_Bar1.MarksLocation = MarksLocation.Center;

_Chart.Series[0].Add(_Bar1);

_Bar2.Add(HistoryBlack, String.Format("{0:0,0.00}%", HistoryBlack));        
_Bar2.Depth = 10;
_Bar2.Pen.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
_Bar2.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
_Bar2.MarksOnBar = true;
_Bar2.MultiBar = MultiBars.Stacked;
_Bar2.Marks.Style = MarksStyles.Label;
_Bar2.Marks.Transparent = true;
_Bar2.Marks.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
_Bar2.Marks.Font.Size = 18;
_Bar2.Marks.Font.Bold = true;
_Bar2.CustomBarWidth = 75;
_Bar2.MarksLocation = MarksLocation.Center;

_Chart.Series[1].Add(_Bar2);
```

It seems that the entire View is destroyed and re-created, which gives a brief flash as it disappears and re-appears.  Is there a way to update the Chart without the flashing?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) No matter what I try, I can't get the View to be transparent - I'd
>   like any underlying View to show through the Chart.

You need to set back wall to transparent too:

```
  _Chart.Walls.Back.Transparent = true;
```

> 2) I can't seem to make the bottom "wall" any deeper - I'd like it to
>   be as deep as the bar depth.

You can change that with *Chart3DPercent*:

```
  _Chart.Aspect.Chart3DPercent = 25;
```

> It seems that the entire View is destroyed and re-created, which gives
>   a brief flash as it disappears and re-appears. Is there a way to
>   update the Chart without the flashing?

Recently we implemented a new feature for MfA which disables both zooming and scrolling:

```
  _Chart.Zoom.Style = Steema.TeeChart.ZoomStyles.None;
```

Since no zoom or scrolling is suppported the chart can render in a more efficient way. The TeeChart Mono for Androis installer contains a real-time charting demo.

Comment: Ok, I tried the new version and using ZoomStyles.None causes a crash in MonoDroid. Additionally, using the repaint=false / repaint=true and Invalidate() technique doesn't update the chart at all. I modified your real time charting sample to reproduce the behaviour and uploaded it at the Steema upload page (it is called ZoomStyleCrashAndRepaintFailure.zip)

Comment: @user1737571 I'm not able to reproduce the problem here using your project. Should I perform anything specific to reproduce it? Which MonoDroid version are you using? I'm not sure whether this test version was built with 4.2.4 or 4.2.5. Also, you may want to try another version: www.steema.us/files/public/RealTimeTeeChartMfADoubleBuffering.zip which uses MfA 4.2.6.

Comment: Hello again, I've tracked this down to being something to do with devices that have the old TeeChart.MonoDroid.dll on.  If I deploy to a different device that hasn't had a TeeChart project on it previously, it appears to work correctly?  It seems that the MonoDroid build scripts aren't updating the dll for some reason, even if I do a clean / rebuild in VS.

Comment: @user1737571 as an update, a maintenance release, implementing the functionality discussed above, has just been published: http://www.steema.com/entry/137/TeeChart_Mono_for_Android_4.0.2012.121203_maintenance_release_available